# Is it possible to style the color of the font?

Tags: mermaid

I would like to change the default black color of the font to white. I tried to add this to the styling section of my graph:

```
style request-rejected fill:#e74c3c,color:#FFFFFF;
```

The background is correctly changed to `#e74c3c` but the font stays black. It looks however that normal CSS styles are used in [the `.less` source](https://github.com/knsv/mermaid/blob/1a3d37d8a52a9c6efcdb24eaa404bdc714bbee1a/src/less/default/flow.less).

**Is it possible to change the font color in a graph?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is a **SUPER** old post - but just in case someone else ends up here...

Please see [Mermaid documentation](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/flowchart?id=styling-and-classes) for information on styling